# Flash socket policy server on different port than 843

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to run a socket server on port 443 to which flash clients can connect.
I don't want to use port 843 to serve the socket policy file as it is often closed by corporate firewalls.

I am now serving the policy file from the socket server on port 443. However, it seems the client closes the connection after I send the policy file. I get this error message:

```
SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false 
cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048: Security sandbox
violation: http://yy.yyy.yyyy.yyyy/path/movie.swf 
cannot load data from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443."]
```

I checked that the policy file is sent successfully:

```
echo -ne '<policy-file-request/>\0' | nc -v xx.xxx.xxx.xxx 443

Connection to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!
<cross-domain-policy>
   <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="443" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Note that the domain from which the swf is loaded (yy.yyy.yyy.yyy) is different from the server address (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try add to policy file:

```
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*"/>
```

Comment: Did you check your firewall and settings on: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/pl/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html ?